# Python Plotly bar chart count items from csv

Tags: python, csv, charts, plotly

I have a csv file with the following structure:

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

input_file = "inf.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
fig = px.bar(df,
             x='Date',
             y='User',
             title='Test',
             color='Items',
             barmode='stack')

fig.show()
```

and this is the output:
[image]

I would like to put on Y axis not the Users, but a number which counts how many users exists in the same day.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get your desired data structure using `df.groupby('Date').count().reset_index()`.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio

#pio.renderers.default = 'jupyterlab'

# Sample data
d={'Date': ['01/08/2019', '01/08/2019', '07/08/2019', '12/08/2019',
            '26/08/2019', '29/08/2019', '29/08/2019'],
   'User':['U1', 'U2', 'U3', 'U4', 'U5', 'U6', 'U7'],
   'Items': ['Pen', 'Ruler', 'Rubber', 'Rubber', 'Ruler', 'Ruler', 'Pen']
  }

# data strucutre
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
dfg=df.groupby('Date').count().reset_index()
dfg=dfg.rename(columns={"User": "Users"})

# plot structure
fig = px.bar(dfg,
             x='Date',
             y='Users',
             title='Test',
             #color='Items',
             barmode='stack')

# plot
fig.show()
```